# how to mark parent element for tree?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

i use gem 'awesome_nested_set'. i made CRUD for model Category and filled DB follow values:

```
science = Category.create!(:title => 'Science')

physics = Category.create!(:title => 'Physics')
physics.move_to_child_of(science)

gravity = Category.create!(:title => 'Gravity')
gravity.move_to_child_of(physics)
```

in result my tree looks:

```
Science
-- Physics
-- -- Gravity
```

in index-template i output all roots elements:
categories_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @categories = Category.roots
end
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <td><%= link_to category.title, category %></td>
<% end %>
```

in show-template i output self_and_descendants elements:
categories_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @categories = Category.find_by_id(params[:id]).self_and_descendants
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <% if category.root? %>
    <strong><%= category.title %></strong>
  <% else %>
    <div style="padding-left: <%= category.level %>0px"><%= link_to category.title, category %></div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

after click on 'Science' on index-page i move to show-page which displays 'Science' wrapped strong-tags and other elements wrapped div-tags. ok.

but after i click on 'Physics' i move to show-page which displays all elements wrapped div-tags.

i need to first element for every show-page always be wrapped by strong-tags

PS:

```
  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "parent_id"
    t.integer  "lft"
    t.integer  "rgt"
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first category isn't always a root. "Root" in this case means an actual *root* category, not just the top-most category in a given context. You'll have to change your display logic to no longer depend on the `root?` method, and instead simply highlight the first category which is seemingly your actual intent:

```
<strong><%= categories.first.title %></strong>

<% @categories[1..-1].each do |category| %>
  <div style="padding-left: <%= category.level %>0px"><%= link_to category.title, category %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks, but <strong><%= @categories.first.title %></strong>